# Transformation matrix - new point coordinate after rotation and transformation

Tags: c++, geometry, openframeworks

Although there is plenty of tutorials on Internet about it, I can't find the proper solution! I'm drawing a line `p1=(0,0); p2=(0,j)` and then I do a `translation(h,k)` and a `rotation(a)`. What is the new coordinate of `p2`?

Here is the general formula I came with after looking at transformation matrix however it doesn't seems to work:

```
x' = (x*cos(a)) + (y*-sin(a)) + h
y' = (x*sin(a)) + (y*cos(a)) + k
```

So my `p2`:

```
x' = (j*-sin(ofDegToRad(a))) + h
y' = (j*cos(ofDegToRad(a))) + k
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

Uploaded the code with answer below, however it is still not working (?). I've put an image with the small sample of code [Here](http://postimg.org/image/d6rxb2p9f/)

When I print the value it says `x = -141.5, y = 254.9`

I would like to get the end point of my line (if start point is in the middle of the window)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equations you show are doing the rotation first then the translate, which is opposite of the order that you said. If you do the translate first, then:

```
x' = x + h
y' = y + k
```

So your p1' is (h, k) and p2' is (h, j+k). Then the rotation is:

```
x' = (x*cos(a)) - (y*sin(a))
y' = (x*sin(a)) + (y*cos(a))
```

Which means your p1'' is

```
( (h*cos(a)) - (k*sin(a)), (h*sin(a)) + (k*cos(a)) )
```

And your p2'' is

```
( (h*cos(a)) - (j+k)*sin(a)), (h*sin(a)) + ((j+k)*cos(a)) ).
```

These all assume that you start with an understood origin at (0,0).

If, instead, we do the rotation first, then we get:

```
p1' = ( 0, 0 ) [when you rotate (0,0) you get (0,0)]
p2' = ( -j*sin(a), j*cos(a) )
```

Then do the translation by (h, k):

```
p1' = ( h, k )
p2' = ( h - j*sin(a), k + cos(a) )
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however it is still not working. I've added a small sample code on my question in case I did not ask the question properly!

Comment: It wasn't clear to me exactly what you're transforming. If you're transforming the segment and not just the endpoint, then you do both points, which I have edited in my answer.

Comment: I'm very sorry to bother you but there is still a problem. For example if my p1 is at (0,0) and then I translate it to (150,150) then rotate it 1.7radians - The answer should give me the point (150,150). However when I apply the formula for `x: (150*cos(1.7)) - (150*sin(1.7))`, the result is `-173.768`!
For y: `(150*sin(1.7)) + (150*cos(1.7)) = 129.42`

Comment: If you rotate the point (150, 150) by 1.7 radians, assuming (0,0) is your origin, you would not get the point (150, 150) because you just rotated it! Rotation is assumed to be about an understood origin, which is (0,0). If (150,150) is actually your origin, then let me know and I can correct the computations. When you say "rotation" it must be understood about what origin you mean.

Comment: It makes sense! I finally understand now. I don't know why my origin has moved to (150,150), maybe with my first translate it has automatically moved it because I did not specify it anywhere in my code. Anyway, I would appreciate the answer for an origin at (150,150) so I'm clear with everything.
Thanks again for your precious help!

Comment: Ahh finally, there is a little something missing in your last answer but it was what I was looking for:
`( (-j*sin(a))+h, (j*cos(a))+k )`
Thanks a lot for your help mbratch!!!

Comment: Good catch. So really, the rotation needed to come first, then the translate. That would have given that answer. I had the order incorrect in my original assumption. I edited my answer to update it accordingly.